# Automatic upgrade of software on windows?

Tags: windows, upgrade

Is there some software on windows that can do automatic unattended upgrades? Much like unattended-upgrades on ubuntu or a version of Secunia PSI that not only notify you but also does an upgrade?

**Edit**: To clarify, I'm looking for a solution that both do system upgrade and installed software upgrade. Much like on Android or Ubuntu with unattended-upgrades

Comment: Upgrades of what? Windows Update will do something like this, but will require reboots (for example).

Comment: What ChrisF said.  If you mean Windows Updates, they already can do this...

Comment: I think grm means everything, OS, programs etc. like it does in Ubuntu. I doubt there is, doing that sounds like the perfect storm on a Windows box.

Comment: @moab yes, I mean everything. Like "automatic update" on android and unattended-updates on ubuntu. I like to keep all machines updated with as little effort as possible.

Comment: @ grm, please edit your original post to include this information.

Comment: @grm: In the case of Linux, you get the indication to update the applications that you have installed from the distro's package manager automatically because it is maintained by the respective distro. But in Window, you only get the automatic updates for Windows OS, related Windows components like .Net and updates related to Microsoft developed applications like the Office, etc. If you install applications from other vendors, usually you get a prompt while installing that says: "Do you want to automatically update the software?".

Comment: @Moab: sorry, I thought it was clear, but I see that it would requiere knowledge about Secunia PSI or unattended-upgrades so I edited it. Thanks! 
@anand: yes, I'm familiar with this. Still if you suggest automatically updates you often need to go through the installation wizard. I'm looking for a solution that does everything automatically so that you don't requiere any user interaction. Android 2.2 works pretty well so it's a good example of the solution I'm looking for also on Windows. Thanks.

Comment: @grm - The issue is with something like, say, Android, it has an app store.  Everything is centralized so it can push updates.  This is not and will NEVER be the case with Windows - you'd have to check every program vendor individually for updates!  (I am sure there is some software that TRIES to do this but it's never going to work for everything or even most things.)  EDIT: Ubuntu won't push updates to packages that come from a third party source either, will they?

Comment: @Shinrai, I'm aware of the central point of Android and agree that the solution would require some central repository. I'm also aware that it wouldn't work on all packages. Solutions like "FileHippo" already provide distribution of 3rd party software and with a repository of "scripts" with knowledge of how to autoupdate each package, it would be possible to create an installer that would be able to do such autoupdates, even on windows today.

Comment: @grm - Sure, it would be possible, but you're talking hundreds of thousands of apps. There's a LOT of software out there for Windows. ;)

Comment: i believe AVAST! Antivirus does this as an integrated feature in the free version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googling a bit (I look for something like that as well) I found

http://www.nabber.org/projects/appupdater/

Looks promising but the [List of supported apps](http://www.nabber.org/projects/appupdater/apps/) is quite small :(

I think I'll give Getit a chance which Tobias suggested, see above.

[TechTracker](http://www.cnet.com/techtracker-free/) looks promising, too. Wanted to test this since some time but never found the time.

[Secunia](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/personal/) or [FileHippo](http://www.filehippo.com/updatechecker/) maybe of interest for you as well.

Finally you can build your own repository using [InstallPad](http://installpad.com/)

Answer (score 2):

It's generally not possible to do Windows Updates with anything else than Windows, not to my knowledge anyway. That's not bad news per se: Windows Update generally works well for Windows and Microsoft applications, so just leave it alone and do it's thing.

So, while there's no unified [package management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system) for Windows like there is for *ix operating systems, there *are* package management systems for Windows. [Wikipedia has a list of them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_package_management_systems#Microsoft_Windows), and from what I can see, [GetIt](http://puchisoft.com/GetIt/) seems pretty good. You're in for some experimentation, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check these applications:

- [Ninite\Ninite Pro](https://ninite.com/%20Ninite%20Pro) (free\non-free) — [supported apps list here](https://ninite.com/applist/pro.html)
- [SUMo (Software Update Monitor)](http://www.kcsoftwares.com/index.php?sumo) (free) — lots of supported apps
- [Soluto](https://www.soluto.com/) (free) — supports Windows Updates and most popular apps
- [Update Notifier](http://cleansofts.org/view/update-notifier.html) (free) — similar to FileHippo Update Checker

You may be also interested in recent Lifehacker article:

[The Best App Updater for Windows](http://lifehacker.com/the-best-app-updater-for-windows-1445085301)

Answer (score 0):

See here for a detailed explanation on "[How to configure and use Automatic Updates in Windows?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306525)"

Comment: Application updates from non-MS vendors are a different matter, though. Its entirely up to the vendors to manage an automatic update process for each application.

Answer (score 0):

You may use command-line package manager, [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), which is much like equivalent to `apt-get`.

For unattended updated, you may use command:

```
cup all -y
```

This is how it looks in action:

[image]

There's also GUI version of the app:

- https://github.com/chocolatey/ChocolateyGUI

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873439/how-do-i-update-all-chocolatey-apps-without-confirmation
- https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CommandsUpgrade